# Deface never find results for rake deface:get_result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree, deface

No matters what selector I try to use in `rake deface:get_result`  it never finds it. 
I've got in code decorator which **WORKS**

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => "spree/checkout/registration",
                     :name => "removes_registration_header",
                     :remove => "h1",
                     :disabled => false)
```

now when I try to do `rake deface:get_result['spree/checkout/registration','h1']` I got answer:
`zsh: no matches found: deface:get_result[spree/checkout/registration,h1]`

How to properly use rake `deface:get_result`?

Note: I also tried to prepend `bundle exec` but results are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use zsh you will need to escape the square brackets or any other special characters like spaces with `\`, you can try something like

```
bundle exec rake deface:get_result\['spree/checkout/registration'\]
```

Also make sure you run rake with `bundle exec` to ensure you are using the correct version of the gem.

From your example, it seems like you are using the `deface:get_result` task incorrectly. It only takes one parameter which is the virtual path of the template. I assume what you are actually trying to do is test a selector, which you can do with

```
bundle exec rake deface:test_selector\['spree/checkout/registration','h1'\]
```